# java/mysql how to get changed data

Tags: java, mysql, jtable

I'm working on a Java program that is connected to a MySQL database. One of the things that I want to do is show if/what data change to a current table has been made. Any ideas?

Comment: change to a current have? what's that?

Comment: I think he/she just wants to get a notification-like (or something similar) when there is an insert/update in the MySQL side

Comment: Yes, something like a notification, but showing only the changed records in the table.

Comment: The only mechanism I can think of is using `triggers` to update a shadow table adding a timestamp to each insert operation and let the application poll that shadow table. But I doubt that has any business value, though it might be a possibility to do it.